# number of functions satisfy given equations

Tags: functions

Number of possible continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ for which $\displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}x^{k}f(x)dx=a^k
$ for $k=0,1,2$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$

what i try

$\displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx=1$ and $\displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}xf(x)dx=a$ and $$\int^{1}_{0}x^2f(x)dx=a^2$$

$$\int^{1}_{0}(x^2-2ax+a^2)f(x)dx=a^2-2a^2+a^2$$

$$\int^{1}_{0}(a-x)^2f(x)dx=0$$

how do i prove that that no function exists help me please

Comment: $\int^{1}_{0}x^{k}f(dx)$ should be $\int^{1}_{0}x^{k}f(x)dx$?@jacky

Comment: An integral is a weak constraint on a function.  It is only one number while a function has an infinite number of degrees of freedom.  I would expect there to be an infinite number of functions that satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Your last is the secret.  My previous answer would create functions that went negative, which are not allowed.  Now if $f(x) \gt 0$ the integral is positive, so there is no such $f(x)$